# Next.js + Tailwind Website Zoomed In in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, next.js

I have developed website using Next.js and Tailwind CSS. The website while testing appears to be zoomed In in Firefox but its looking fine in all other browsers.

When the screen is broguht to 80%, then the website looks fine in firefox. What's the solution to this problem so that the website should appear same in all browser.

Thanks
[image: This is the website image in firefox][image: This is the website Image in Chrome]

Comment: Beside checking if your other browser isn't already also zoomed out at 80%? Then your question is probably going to be downvoted if you don't provide any code.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try to use css reset  in the globalStyle.css file.
just copy the reset from the following [Link](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) .
that should resolve your problem

Comment: Thank you but it couldn't work. I don't know why this issue is happening on firefox and just fine with all other browsers. But thanks for your kind reply!

Comment: you have a git hub repo for that project? maybe i can take a look

Comment: I found out the reason. The website came to me for customization and some additions. I look up the website code and found that the CSS ''Zoom'' property is used on the production site. But the firefox does not supports this. That's the main reason. Thank you for your  time and cooperation!

Answer (score 0):

CSS Zoom property was used on the product site to set the layout. Avoid using this property as far as you can because firefox does not supports this property.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone still looking for the solution, add the below in your head block. It did the trick for me.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover"></meta>
```